# How does IMU pre-integration work and how is it different from EKF?

Tags: slam, imu, visual-odometry

My understanding is that IMU pre-integration is to get away from having to re-integrate the the IMU between key-frame intervals when doing bundle adjustment. The formulations I ave seen involve a complicated computation involving SO(3) manifold. I'm curious, why not just propagate the IMU state change by linearizing the function as in EKF? At the end of the sequence you should still get an expected state offset which is gaussian distributed according to a particular covariance matrix(assuming additive gaussian noise). Why involve this additional Lie-Group theory?

Comment: Are you sure the EKFs that you're referring to aren't doing the rotation as an SO(3) "complicated computation"?  (Aside -- quaternions aren't _that_ hard).  Could you _edit your question_ with citations showing how the EKF deals with rotations from the vehicle body frame of reference to the global frame of reference?  Typically with an EKF you calculate the update as $x^-_k = f(x^+_{k-1}, u_k)$, then calculate $F_k = \nabla f(x^-_{k-1}, u_k)$ for use in the covariance update.  At least when I did this, my $f(x^+_{k-1}, u_k)$ embedded rotations using quaternion (i.e., SO(3)) math.

Comment: For example: https://limhyungtae.github.io/2022-04-01-IMU-Preintegration-(Easy)-4.-Derivation-of-Preintegrated-IMU-Measurements/ the author derives the preintegration formula but it's effectively the same as just linearizing the IMU dynamics and using the error-state kalman filter.